# Check if all ids exist in repo

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

I can check if ID exists in my repo using this query:

```
exists(String id);
```

But what query can i use to find out if all elements of a list exist in my repo? Something like this?

```
existAll(List<String> id);
```

Comment: Are you talking about the `exists` method in `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters` or some other `exists`? It's not really clear what you are asking without more context.

Comment: How about fetching ID column for the List of records and compare the size of returned records?

Comment: thats a `MongoRepository` query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using built-in methods I see only one option: getting all of the records using [findAllById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findAllById-java.lang.Iterable-) and then checking the size. This is bad, because you have to check the existance yourself (by comparing the size of the result) and you are getting whole records when you don't need them.

I suggest writing your own method, preferably doing the count of records which ID's are in the list of your ID's. I think it would be something like this, not really familiar with Mongo:

`db.collection.count({ id: { $in: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } });`

You could just add a method to your repository, like this:

```html
public interface YourRepository extends MongoRepository<YourItem, String> {
    Long countByIdIn(List<String> ids);
}
```